Check incomplete line in fgets()
To detect it, I've seen the following if condition:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
  char line[5];
  while(fgets(line, 5, stdin)){
    int length = strlen(line);
    if (length == 4 && line[3] != '\n') {
      puts("line too long");
      return 1;
    }
  }
  puts("correct file");
  return 0;
}

which works here:
$ cc test.c -o test
$ printf '012\n' | ./test
correct file
$ printf '012' | ./test
correct file
$ printf '0123\n' | ./test
line too long

but fails when the length is equal to the maximum and it doesn't have a trailing newline:
$ printf '0123' | ./test
line too long

The detection was incorrect as the entire line fits in the buffer; there is no more to read from the file.

Simpler, and without knowing the length, is if (strchr (line, '\n') == NULL). Aside: don't be tight with your buffer sizes. Allow room for the whole of a reasonable but mistaken input.

The test is correct unless you want to allow an unterminated line at the end of the stream to be one character longer than is allowed for all the previous lines.


the entire line fits in the buffer; there is no more to read from the file.

So check that,
The function feof() checks if the previous operation ended on eof. If fgets read 4 characters, it did not end on eof, it ended reading after 4 characters. You have to peek "one more" character in front to trigger setting eof.
ungetc(fgetc(stdin), stdin);
if (length == 4 && (line[3] != '\n' || feof(stdin))) {

Or:
if (length == 4) {
  int c = getc(stdin);
  if (c == EOF) break;
  ungetc(c, stdin);
  if (line[3] != '\n') {
    puts("line too long");
    return 1;
  }
}


That's not what feof() does?

hi @IsidroArias you approved the answer, but I do not think it works. To trigger feof there has to be a read first.... I think it imght be better to fgetc and check for EOF

Pedantically ungetc(fgetc(stdin), stdin); if (length == 4 && (line[3] != '\n' || feof(stdin))) { is a problem should fgetc(stdin) return EOF due to an input error.  Yet that rare event inside the loop, we can ignore for a learner.

@KamilCuk Think it would improve with int c = getc(stdin);  if (c == EOF) break;  ungetc(c, stdin); inside the  if (line[3] != '\n') {} block?  That is: avoid the get/unget unless needed?

feof does not "check if the previous operation ended on eof".  That's not its purpose.  If you want to know if getc returned EOF, you check the value returned by getc.  If getc returns EOF, then you use feof to test the end-of-file indicator for the stream to know whether the getc returned EOF because there was no more data to read, and you use ferror to know whether EOF was returned because of an error condition.

The call to fgetc will block if reading from a terminal in canonical input mode.

FWIW, I do like @KamilCuk approach that does not require extra space.
Alternative
A common approach is to attempt to read at least 1 more than the expected maximum. @WeatherVane: Allow room for the whole of a reasonable but mistaken input.
#define LINE_LEN_MAX 4

int main(){
  char line[LINE_LEN_MAX + 1 /* too long detection */ + 1 /* \0 */];
  while(fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)){
    size_t length = strlen(line);
    if (length > LINE_LEN_MAX) {
      puts("line too long");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // Robust code would check for errors. 
  if (ferror(stdin)) {
    puts("Trouble reading");
    return -1;
  }
   
  puts("correct file");
  return 0;
}

Note: Reading a null character renders length = strlen(line); insufficient.
Leave that issue for another day.

Detected ... and then?
Even after detecting an overlong line, what is still missing is how to gracefully cope with it?
For learner code, simply enough to exit.
Commonly after detection, the rest of the overly long line needs to be consumed too.  Various approaches exist.
